# How to build xdb index in Sitecore 9.1.1?

Tags: xdb, xconnect

We need to rebuild xdb index in Sitecore 9.1.1. I am new in Sitecore. Kindly someone assist me how can I rebuild xdb index in Sitecore 9.1.1.

Comment: It's all there in Sitecore documentation https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/rebuilding-the-xdb-search-index.html

Answer (score 2):

You can find it here - https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/rebuilding-the-xdb-search-index.html

Some important steps after creating xDB core -

To invoke the rebuild request command:

1. Go to the server where the xConnect Search Indexer is running and open a command line.
2. Go to the xConnect Collection Search IndexWorker folder: `<xConnect Collection Search service root>\App_Data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker`.
3. Run `XConnectSearchIndexer -rr` (alternatively XConnectSearchIndexer `-requestrebuild`). The command registers a small document in the live core signaling that the rebuild should be started. The xConnect Search Indexer will notice the document and start the rebuild process.

Note - Check in Sitecore 9.3 it is `Sitecore.XConnectSearchIndexer` instead of `XConnectSearchIndexer`

Comment: Getting an error `"Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 ().` while running `XConnectSearchIndexer -rr` command

Comment: did you find XConnectSearchIndexer in above folder, check if the name is Sitecore.XConnectSearchIndexer then try to run "Sitecore.XConnectSearchIndexer -requestrebuild" but if you find XConnectSearchIndexer then hen try to run "XConnectSearchIndexer -requestrebuild"

Comment: Resolved that issue but now getting this issue :`[Error] Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.XdbSearchOperation`1[Sitecore.XConnect.Contact]: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 ({"Message":"The index 'xdb' for service 'xxxxxxx' was not found."}).`